# Obtaining peak values from graph?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, spectrogram

Here is my code:

```
   spectro.stop();
   var freqData = new Uint8Array(spectro.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
   analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);
   document.getElementById("frec").value = freqData;
```

I have added this function in this

[Github Repo](https://github.com/miguelmota/spectrogram/blob/master/README.md)

to obtain peak vales from spectrogram. but it is not displaying any information

Comment: @torek can you help

Comment: No; I just removed the `git` tag, which is described in the [tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info) this way: "Use this tag for questions related to Git usage and workflows. Do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository." I suspect you should not be using the javascript tag either, but rather a tag specific to whatever this "spectro" thing is.